# Mount a disk over another disk

Tags: filesystems, mount, drupal

I have a Drupal website on a VM (RHEL 7) and it works on an SSD storage both public and private directories: `/storage/drupalpublic` and `/storage/drupalprivate`.

Now and in the future, I need to store a lot of gigabytes of data, but the SSD is definitely not a good way because of the price.

Can I attach a regular hard drive and mount it like `data1` over the private folder like that: `/storage/drupalprivate/data1`?

Is it OK or will there be some interference between the SSD and regular hard drive?

Do I have to place them in a some particular order in `fstab`?

Will drupal understand all of that or it does not matter for it?

Comment: Yes you can mount additional devices as part of the / partition via folders that you create within it. These are called mount points and you can mount them however you like under /. Drupal will know no difference. As far as it's concerned, it's a local directory on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disks can be mounted on any directories, there are however pitfall.

1. all disk must be mounted before application (e.g. drupal)  is started.
2. "deepest" directories must be mounted last (e.g mount `/storage/drupalprivate/` before `/storage/drupalprivate/data1` ).
3. any existing file or dir under `/storage/drupalprivate/data1` on your SSD disk, will be unavailable/hide once you mount `/storage/drupalprivate/data1` from other disk.

your `/etc/fstab` will look like (among other lines)

```
/dev/sdb            /storage/drupalprivate/              ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/sdc            /storage/drupalprivate/data1         ext4    defaults        1 2
```

assuming /dev/sdb is SSD disk and /dev/sdc is 'normal' disk.